# Как заново перепройти текстовый файл, когда строки в нем закончились?

Tags: python

Для работы итеративного скрипта мне необходимо построчно читать текстовый файл постоянно, пока не закончится время работы скрипта. Т.е. на каждую итерацию скрипта необходима одна строка текстового файла. Но количество итераций может в десятки, сотни и тысячи раз превосходить количество строк в файле. Соответственно, когда последняя строка окажется пустой мне необходимо вернуть контекстный менеджер на первую строку и так постоянно, пока не закончится работа скрипта.

Выглядит это примерно так:

```
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as damp:
    while True: #здесь будет ограничение по времени работы скрипта
        line = damp.readline()
        if not line:
            ??? #здесь надо начать заново читать файл
        do_something
```

Знаю, что есть специальная команда возврата к первой строке, но не могу ее нагуглить. И подойдет ли она для полного перезапуска построчного чтения файла или я просто вернусь к первой строке, а в следующей итерации условие `if not line:` снова вернет `True`?

Comment: В течение итерации по циклу файл будет изменяться?

Comment: @Effex вообще должен меняться, но пока это не реализовано и я работаю со статическим файлом

Comment: ну первое незатейливое решение, которое приходит в голову, это при открытии файла сразу считать все строки в список через readlines(). С помощью списка такую логику легко можно реализовать, единственная проблема в том, что когда файл будет изменяться, нужно будет его записывать снова

Comment: но если там не требуются актуальные данные на момент каждой итерации, то можно это сделать 1 раз после завершения цикла

Comment: и еще при условии, что файл не будет меняться извне. В этом случае список будет неактуален

Comment: @Effex в целом решение подойдет, спасибо. Но не совсем понимаю, почему не получится проделывать такое, если файл менять извне? Файл нужно будет обновлять раз в час - загружая новый через API сервиса, который предоставляет этот файл.

Comment: @Effex обновления планирую делать так: подключиться к сервису и загрузить из него строки в другой файл(не в тот, который я читаю в скрипте). После того, как файл загрузился, подменить его в тот, который я читаю в скрипте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144640/discussion-between-vsevolod-and-effex).

Answer (score 2):

Не самая лучшая практика в данном случае работать напрямую с файлом, но тем не менее, используя [seek(0)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=seek#io.IOBase.seek) можно вернуться в начало файла

файл test.txt

```
hello
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

добавим `row5` в конец, проверим по условию его наличие и выйдем из цикла:

```
with open('test.txt','r+', encoding='utf-8') as damp:
    while True:
        line = damp.readline()
        print(line)
        if line == 'row5':
            break
        if not line:
            damp.write('\nrow5')
            print('----добавили row5----')
            damp.seek(0)
```

Вывод:

```
hello

row1

row2

row3

row4

----добавили row5----
hello

row1

row2

row3

row4

row5
```

Comment: спасибо! именно seek(0) я и имел ввиду. А почему вы говорите `Не самая лучшая практика в данном случае работать напрямую с файлом`. Какие могут быть последствия? И какую практику тогда лучше использовать?

Comment: @Vsevolod я бы использовал метод описанный пользователем Effex, создавая список из строк файла, а в последствии работая со списком, а далее переписывая файл обработанным списком, так гораздо безопаснее.

Comment: @Vsevolod последствия могут быть такие, что что-то извне может так же работать с этим файлом, может нарушиться последовательность. Например, программа1 добавляет строку в середину файла, программа2 в этот момент может читать вторую половину файла, пропуская информацию о первой половине файла

Comment: @Vsevolod либо же наоборот, когда программа2 не ожидает увидеть строку созданную программой1, в середине документа при чтении первой половины, такие моменты геморно обрабатывать

Comment: @Vsevolod хотя говоря о практиках реальной жизни, txt документы могут формировать собой специальные структуры для "банк-клиентов" (о таких вещах стоит почитать в интернете), там идет работа с тэгами по типу "Получатель=" или "ИНН=" и т.д., в таком случае данная практика очень даже неплохо будет показывать себя

Comment: понял! Огромное спасибо за развернутые ответы вам и @Effex